# por que hay diferencia en la dimension de las imagenes en Chrome y Firefox

Tags: html, css

por que esta diferencia en las imagenes es decir en chrome la imagen se ve desformada mientras que en Firefox se ve como espero mi codigo para ajustar las imagenes es el siguinete :

```css
.dark{

display: flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items: center;
padding: 0px;


}
.dark img{

 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 max-height:550px;

}
```

```html
      <div class="dark">
           <div>
    
         <img id="img"  src="https://i.imgur.com/x8SPZUF.jpg"> 
               
         </div>
      </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen de la derecha es la que se ve correcta es decir la de fire fox

hay alguna propiedad css que uno o el otro no soporte o que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es algo relacionado a cómo se escalan las imágenes (cuando se estiran) prueba con [`object-fit: scale-down;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```css
.dark {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%
}

.dark img {
  object-fit: scale-down;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark">
  <div>

    <img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/x8SPZUF.jpg">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias!! @alo Malbarez no savia aserca de `object-fit: scale-down;`